# Passing value to another prototype function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Getting into the Javascript prototype, I have no idea why when I call one prototype function from another and pass value to another, the value does not get updated.

Is that some problem related to closure? I tried to use global variable but still doesn't work.
Any assistance?

```
function test(elem){
   this.opt = 
   this.elem = $(elem)
   this.method1();
}

test.prototype.method1 = function() {
   var output = 1;
   this.method2(output);
   console.log(output);
}

test.prototype.method2 = function(output) {
   output += 1;
}

var data = new test(this);
```

When I call method2 in method1 function, the output will not get updated, it will still console 1 as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `method2`, `output` is a variable on that function's scope.
It doesn't point to the `output` in `method1`.

You're going to have to return the new value from `method2`:

```
test.prototype.method1 = function() {
    var output = 1;
    output = this.method2(output);
    console.log(output);
}

test.prototype.method2 = function(output) {
   return output + 1;
}
```

Comment: `return output + 1;` would be better, since there's no point to modifying `output`.

Comment: @YunhanLi: Thanks ;-) Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is basically [reference vs value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)

> Javascript is always pass by value, but when a variable refers to an
> object (including arrays), the "value" is a reference to the object.
>
> Changing the value of a variable never changes the underlying
> primitive or object, it just points the variable to a new primitive or
> object.
>
> However, changing a property of an object referenced by a
> variable does change the underlying object.

You have 3 posibilities:

1. Wrap the variable in an object: http://jsfiddle.net/8c2p349g/

```js
function test(elem, opt){
       this.opt = opt;
       this.elem = $(elem);
       this.method1();
    }
    
    test.prototype.method1 = function() {
        var data = {
            output: 1
        };
       this.method2(data);
       console.log(data.output);
    }
    
    test.prototype.method2 = function(data) {
       data.output += 1;
    }
    
    var inst = new test();
```

2. Return `output` from `method2`: http://jsfiddle.net/8c2p349g/1/

```js
function test(elem, opt){
       this.opt = opt;
       this.elem = $(elem);
       this.method1();
    }
    
    test.prototype.method1 = function() {
       var output = 1;
       output = this.method2(output);
       console.log(output);
    }
    
    test.prototype.method2 = function(output) {
       return output + 1;
    }
    
    var inst = new test();
```

3. Attach `output` as property of `test`:  http://jsfiddle.net/8c2p349g/2/

```js
function test(elem, opt){
       this.opt = opt;
       this.elem = $(elem);
       this.method1();
    }
    
    test.prototype.method1 = function() {
       this.output = 1;
       this.method2(this.output);
       console.log(this.output);
    }
    
    test.prototype.method2 = function(output) {
       this.output += 1;
    }
    
    var inst = new test();
```

Comment: A wrapper object? seriously?

Comment: what's the problem with my answer ? 10x more educative than yours ?

Comment: @CristiPufu: Of course it's more educational *after* the comment was made.  Before that, it was pretty bad.

Comment: in my opinion the real problem that the user had, was not being able to make the difference between `reference and value`, and my answer explained it. The later edit, covered all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

The `output` is a local variable of `method1`, it does not exist in the scope of `method2`.